# Upload file in codeigniter only loading

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

can anyone help me? Previously my website could upload images normally, but yesterday the website couldn't upload files, only loading. I use Codeigniter and windows server. And I tried to make a simple image upload, but it still can't be uploaded. You can try it in adilayaindonesia.com/Gambar

Controller

class Gambar extends CI_Controller{

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('v_upload', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function aksi_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.'/upload/Cobagambar';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('berkas')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('v_upload', $error);
    }else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('v_upload_sukses', $data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try to debug `$error`

Comment: I have tried it, there are no errors, I tried it on localhost the file can be uploaded smoothly